# Nested IF ELSE condition and logic not working for some reason

Tags: powershell, if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements

Why doesn't ELSE work below?  Syntax and flow appears to be correct for conditions. I am interested to learn why the logic below doesn't work.

**Current output**
File exists!*

**Expected output:**
File exists!
This condition is also true. But ignored by script!

---

For whatever reason, the line for "ELSE" isn't executing below... **even though I've already confirmed that $File exists and $FileLeaseGood = $null**

The way I was reading my script, the "ELSE" is specific for the $FileLeaseGood IF statement, not the $File exists IF-statement.

```
$File = gi "P:\tmp\MKA.theme"
$lastWrite = (get-item $File).LastWriteTime
$timespan = new-timespan -hours 8
$FileLeaseGood = $NULL
if (((get-date) - $lastWrite) -le $timespan) {$FileLeaseGood = $True}

if (Test-Path $File) {
    write-host "File exists!"
    if ($FileLeaseGood) {

        write-host "File exists! and File Lease still good"

    }} else {

        #Why doesn't this else condition work???
        Write-host "This condition is also true. But ignored by script!"
    }
```

Comment: What is your output after running this? Which write-host does get executed?

Comment: `write-host` != `Write-host`?

Comment: They way this is coded that if the file does not exist "The condition is true". This is just bracket placement issue.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel No. PowerShell is case-insensitive there.

Comment: I updated the first post so it's clear what line isn't executing, even though I can verify the conditions are met.

Comment: This is a "typo" question - a single closing brace was swapped accidentally for a double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean for this to happen? One of your closing braces was not in the right spot if your if/else was to be completely nested. The code was executing as it was designed. Sounds like what you *meant* to happen was this.

```
if (Test-Path $File) {
    write-host "File exists!"
    if ($FileLeaseGood) {
        write-host "File exists! and File Lease still good"        
    } else {
        Write-host "This condition is true."
    }
}
```

Changing the spacing and indentation a little, to prove a point, this is what you had before for comparison.

```
if (Test-Path $File) {
    write-host "File exists!"
    if ($FileLeaseGood) {
        write-host "File exists! and File Lease still good"
    } # <--- New Line place here is the visual change you should notice.
} else {
    #Why doesn't this else condition work???
    Write-host "This condition is true. But ignored!"
}
```

The else condition you have here would fire if `$file` did not exist. That should be a sufficient explanation to cover what was happening and what you need to do to fix it.

Comment: Oops... I just read more carefully what you said.  I was expecting the ELSE to be specific to if $FileLeaseGood isn't there.  Not, if $file isn't there.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MKANET You placed a bracket in the wrong place so the else clause was being applied to the `if (Test-Path $File)` instead of the inner if like you wanted it to. Use my _first_ code snippet and it should work as you intended

Answer (score -1):

Matt's last explanation gave me the idea what I was doing wrong; now, it makes perfect sense.  I was just putting the ELSE in the wrong place.  Below is the way I "EXPECTED" for it to work originally.

```Pos
$File = gi "P:\tmp\MKA.theme"
$lastWrite = (get-item $File).LastWriteTime
$timespan = new-timespan -hours 8
$FileLeaseGood = $NULL
if (((get-date) - $lastWrite) -le $timespan) {$FileLeaseGood = $True}

if (Test-Path $File) {
    write-host "File exists!"
    if ($FileLeaseGood) {
        write-host "File exists! and File Lease still good"
    } else {Write-host "This condition is true. But not ignored anymore!"
}
}
```